# How to write Regional Setting code in Java

Tags: java, vba, vbscript, regional-settings

Can someone please help me understanding below VB code.
I have to write its corresponding Java code. But I am not able to understand the VB code.This is regarding modifying regional settings.

```
Dim sTemp As String
mstrDecimalSepChar = OS_GetRegionalSetting(DecimalSeparator)
OS_SetRegionalSetting DecimalSeparator, "."
sTemp = OS_GetRegionalSetting(DecimalSeparator)

mstrThousandsSepChar = OS_GetRegionalSetting(ThousandsSeparator)
OS_SetRegionalSetting ThousandsSeparator, ","
sTemp = sTemp & OS_GetRegionalSetting(ThousandsSeparator)

SetRegionalSettings = (sTemp = ".,")
```

Comment: If you want to get advice of vb experts, I guess, you should tag this question with vb tag

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sTemp As String

mstrDecimalSepChar = OS_GetRegionalSetting(DecimalSeparator)       ' save current system setting for the separator
OS_SetRegionalSetting DecimalSeparator, "."                        ' set separator to "."

mstrThousandsSepChar = OS_GetRegionalSetting(ThousandsSeparator)   ' save current system setting for the separator
OS_SetRegionalSetting ThousandsSeparator, ","                      ' set separator to ","

sTemp = OS_GetRegionalSetting(DecimalSeparator)                    ' retrieve the system settings of the two separators
sTemp = sTemp & OS_GetRegionalSetting(ThousandsSeparator)

SetRegionalSettings = (sTemp = ".,")                               ' return True if separators are now "." and "," in system settings
```